# Should you use properties to initialize your fields in the constructor?

Tags: c#, properties, encapsulation

Pretty simple question really, should I use my properties to initialize fields in the constructor or reference them directly?

Example:

```
public class Foo()
{
   private string example;

   public String Example
   {
      get/set etc..
   }

   public Foo(string exampleIn)
   {
      Example = exampleIn;
   }
}
```

Or is it better practice to do this:

```
public class Foo()
{
   private string example;

   public String Example
   {
      get/set etc..
   }

   public Foo(string exampleIn)
   {
      example = exampleIn;
   }
}
```

Either way, I don't think either would violate encapsulation so I am wondering if there is a preferred way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before automatic properties, which were introduced in C# 3.0, your second example is more "proper" in my opinion.  Now with automatic properties I think this is best:

```
public class Foo()
{
   private string example;

   public String Example
   {
      { get; set; }
   }

   public Foo(string exampleIn)
   {
      Example = exampleIn;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured as much but was just curious to see if there was any sort of "standard" since C#3.0 makes this so easy to do.

Answer (score 2):

There is really no right or wrong answer here (and because of that I am almost tempted to vote to close). But, I tend to agree with [Jacob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15416197/158779) on this. I prefer the property getter and setter route especially now that we have automatic properties. Do keep in mind that you can have different access modifies on the getters and setters in case that influences your decision for any reason. I mean, if you are going to use the property in the constructor then try to be consistent and use it exclusively everywhere else in the class as well. That may mean that you do not want to expose the setter to the outside.

```
public class Foo()
{
   private string example;

   public String Example
   {
     get { return example; }
     private set { example = value; }
   }

   public Foo(string exampleIn)
   {
      Example = exampleIn;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether the data value will further be processed inside the Setter. IF the value needs processing then it's better to use what @Jacob has said but if the value will not be further processed (which is the case in most scenarios), it's better to use the private member to avoid an extra method call to setter method. When CLR compiles the code, it create two methods for Get and Set property and using the Property to access/modify the value which defines the property will result in extra method call unnecessarily (if the value is not processed further).